# addClass added a class but wont change the css of it?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a Jquery method that adds a class with an `addClass()` , it suppose to add a class named "`active`" when you click on the div.

it works perfectly, because I can see in firebug that it does add the class name "active".

```
 <div class="rateWrapper L">
        <div class="upV rateBtn">
        </div>
        <div class="numV largeFont">
            5
        </div>
        <div class="dwnV rateBtn">
        </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is, that I can't see the css changes.

this is my css :

```
.wrapper .tutVWrapper .rateWrapper .upV .rateBtn .active{ background:url('../img/up_V_active.png');}
.wrapper .tutVWrapper .rateWrapper .numV{ font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 15px; margin-top: 15px; text-align: center;}
.wrapper .tutVWrapper .rateWrapper .dwnV{ background:url('../img/dwn_V_none.png'); width: 20px; height: 20px; cursor: pointer;}
.wrapper .tutVWrapper .rateWrapper .dwnV .rateBtn .active{ background:url('../img/dwn_V_active.png'); }
```

how can I solve this pickle?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both classes belong to the same element, there is no space in the CSS rule between the class names.  A space means "any descendant of".

so for example `.upv .rateBtn .active` should be `.upv.rateBtn.active`

Answer (score 3):

I don't know to which element you are adding the `active` class, but judging from your HTML - to elements that also have `rateBtn` as a class.

Your CSS is separated by spaces at `.rateBtn .active` making the `.active` apply only to children elements of `.rateBtn`. I guess you wanted to write `.rateBtn.active`.